# Sharepoint 2013 Need hashtags to work throughout site

Tags: hashtags

We are in the process of deploying a Sharepoint 2013 4 server farm at our company.  We've had pretty good success getting it done, but are hitting a wall here with the hashtag system.

Currently, hashtags work on certain pages (mysites, newsfeed, main pages) but not everywhere.  They're not necessarily picked up on subsites.  Like if I join a discussion on a subsite, and #hashtag, it doesn't recognize it as a hashtag and also doesn't find it on the crawl.  We want hashtags to work on the site and everything in/under it.  What am I missing here?

Thanks, Everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on "Community Site Feature" for the sites you're referring to?

Site Settings > Site Features > Community Site Feature

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, it is, but thanks for the suggestion.